# Pegando valores String e separando-os

Tags: android

Ex.:

(TextView)resultado = "texto1;texto2;texto3;texto4" ;

quero pegar eles em sequencia e fazer da seguinte forma, para depois poder manipular separadamente.

String tx1 = "texto1";
String tx2 = "texto2";
String tx3 = "texto3";
String tx4 = "texto4";

Comment: já li e "acho" que o método "indexOf" faz isso, mas não sei como utilizar :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
String [] pedaços = resultado.split(";");
```

Cada item do array `pedaços` terá um dos textos entre os pontos-e-vírgulas. Exemplo:

```
Log.v("Teste", "Texto 1 = " + pedaços[0]); // Imprime Texto 1 = texto1
```

Comment: Perfeito cara :)